# How to make Locust respect DNS TTL

Tags: dns, locust, ttl

I'm distributed locust using the [provided terraform on AWS](https://github.com/locustio/locust/tree/master/examples/terraform/aws). Between the load, I update the route53 weighted records of my target to point to another version.

What I see is that locust don't update the initial DNS resolution, and keep targetting my first version.

How can I make locust to recalculate the dns resolution during the load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is kind of hard, as your OS will most likely cache the dns resolution.

You could use `dnspython` to resolve the address yourself (https://blog.devgenius.io/pyops-dnspython-toolkit-590a368b5c2)

```
A = dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'A')
for answer in A.response.answer:
    for item in answer.items:
        ip = item.address
```

And then do the request against that ip, manually adding the appropriate `Host` header.

```
self.client.get(f"http://{ip}", headers={"Host": domain})
```

Edit: if using OS dns resolution is ok or even desirable, then maybe just creating a new `Session` is enough. That creates a new tcp connection and should trigger a new DNS query once any OS level caching times out:

```
from locust.clients import HttpSession

...
    
@task
def t(self):
    self.client.close()
    self.client = HttpSession(
        base_url=self.host,
        request_event=self.environment.events.request,
        user=self
    )
    # your actual requests
```

Comment: Thanks. The OS resolution is OK and respect the TTL, but maybe it is on purpose for locust to have better performance on injection.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover that case too

Comment: Thanks It works fine with your edit :)